# How do I re-declare index of @Embedded using Room for Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

Using the Room annotation @Embedded is a handy way of flattening out a 1:1 hierarchy to be able to work easier with it from Java/Kotlin, but I am having trouble understanding and getting rid of the [warnings related to an associated index](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomWarnings) of the embedded column.

The schema looks like this:

```
@Entity
class TicketRecord {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = ""

    @Embedded(prefix = "origin_")
    var origin: TicketLocationRecord? = null
}

@Entity(foreignKeys = [(ForeignKey(entity = TicketRecord::class, parentColumns = arrayOf("id"), childColumns = arrayOf("ticketRecordId"), onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))],
    indices = [Index("ticketRecordId")])
class TicketLocationRecord {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = ""

    // ForeignKey
    var ticketRecordId: String? = null
}
```

I keep getting the following warning:

```
warning: Indices defined in TicketLocationRecord will be dropped when it is merged into TicketRecord (origin). You can re-declare them in TicketRecord. - origin in TicketRecord
private TicketLocationRecord origin;
```

Even if I try to redeclare the indices like the following:

```
@Entity(indices = [
Index(value = ["origin_ticketRecordId"], unique = true)
])
class TicketRecord {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = ""

    @Embedded(prefix = "origin_")
    var origin: TicketLocationRecord? = null
}
```

How do I get rid of the warning, either by suppressing them (I guess they are no longer really needed?) or actually fixing it by re-declaring them?

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by adding the following to `TicketRecord`

```
@SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.INDEX_FROM_EMBEDDED_ENTITY_IS_DROPPED)
```

or

```
@SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.INDEX_FROM_EMBEDDED_FIELD_IS_DROPPED)
```

see which one works.

I think you dont need to redeclare the index as the var with the index is basicaly the same value as id in `TicketRecord` and id is the primary key. I think primary keys are indexed by default in sql.

I am impressed that origin_ticketRecordId is even added to the merged table. it is redundant right?

Comment: This didn't help for me. Any updates on this? Thanks.